# JQuery get title values based on text in different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery and I want to get data from one site but run in problem with getting that data.

I have list like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="hero">
    <p class="heroname">Hero1</p>
        <ul class="stats">
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="42">someText</span>
                <span class="description">strength</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="15">someText</span>
                <span class="description">defence</span>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li class="hero">
        <p class="heroname">Hero2</p>
            <ul class="stats">
                <li>
                    <span class="herostats" title="18">someText</span>
                    <span class="description">strength</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="herostats" title="33">someText</span>
                    <span class="description">defence</span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    <!--and so on with other heros...-->
</ul>
```

And I want to get values from `title` tag in first `span`, but those `spans` have same `class`, so only difference between those two `li` tags are texts in the second `span` tag.

I have already tried this:

```
data = [];

$(".list > li").each(function() {
    obj = {};

    obj.name = $(this).find("heroname").text();
    obj.str = $(this).find("herostats").attr("title");
    obj.defe = $(this).find("herostats").attr("title");

    data.push(obj);
});

jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(jsonData);
```

but this gives me only values from the first `li` tag.

my output: `[{"name":"hero1","str":"42","defe","42"},{"name":"hero2","str":"18","def":"18"}...]`

desired output: `[{"name":"hero1","str":"42","def","15"},{"name":"hero2","str":"18","defe":"33"}...]`

Thank for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is based on [eq-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```js
$(function () {
  data = [];

  $(".list > li").each(function() {
    obj = {};

    obj.name = $(this).find(".heroname").text();
    obj.str = $(this).find(".herostats:eq(0)").attr("title");
    obj.defe = $(this).find(".herostats:eq(1)").attr("title");

    data.push(obj);
  });
  document.body.innerHTML += 'Result: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
    <li class="hero">
        <p class="heroname">Hero1</p>
        <ul class="stats">
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="42">someText</span>
                <span class="description">strength</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="15">someText</span>
                <span class="description">defence</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hero">
        <p class="heroname">Hero2</p>
        <ul class="stats">
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="18">someText</span>
                <span class="description">strength</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="33">someText</span>
                <span class="description">defence</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!--and so on with other heros...-->
</ul>
```

Comment: Work pretty fine, and in case they add more stats i can add next line with eq() and get also those data.

Answer (score 1):

In your question code, you are using `find("heroname")`, which should be `find(".heroname")`.

Since there are 2 elements with `".herostats"` in each items, you can use `first()` and `last()` functions. Also it is better to use `map()` than using each loop in these scenarios.

```js
data = $(".list > li").map(function() {
  return {
    'name' : $(this).find(".heroname").text(),
    'str' : $(this).find(".herostats").first().attr("title"),
    'defe' : $(this).find(".herostats").last().attr("title")
  };
});

jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
document.write(jsonData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="hero">
    <p class="heroname">Hero1</p>
    <ul class="stats">
      <li>
        <span class="herostats" title="42">someText</span>
        <span class="description">strength</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="herostats" title="15">someText</span>
        <span class="description">defence</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hero">
    <p class="heroname">Hero2</p>
    <ul class="stats">
      <li>
        <span class="herostats" title="18">someText</span>
        <span class="description">strength</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="herostats" title="33">someText</span>
        <span class="description">defence</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!--and so on with other heros...-->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the class identifier '.' in your code. Here is the updated one :

---

```
$(".list > li").each(function(){
obj = {};

obj.name = $(this).find(".heroname").text();
obj.str = $(this).find(".herostats:first").attr("title");
obj.defe = $(this).find(".herostats:last").attr("title");

data.push(obj);
});

jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the last `li` inside each `stat` `ul` then

Replace this line

```
$(".list > li").each(function(){
```

by

```
$(".list ul.stats li:last-child").each(function(){
```

**DEMO**

```js
data = [];

$(".list ul.stats li:last-child").each(function(){
obj = {};

obj.name = $(this).parent().prev(".heroname").text();
obj.str = $(this).find(".herostats").attr("title");
obj.defe = $(this).find(".herostats").attr("title");

data.push(obj);
});

jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(jsonData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="hero">
    <p class="heroname">Hero1</p>
        <ul class="stats">
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="42">someText</span>
                <span class="description">strength</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="herostats" title="15">someText</span>
                <span class="description">defence</span>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li class="hero">
        <p class="heroname">Hero2</p>
            <ul class="stats">
                <li>
                    <span class="herostats" title="18">someText</span>
                    <span class="description">strength</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="herostats" title="33">someText</span>
                    <span class="description">defence</span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    <!--and so on with other heros...-->
</ul>
```